# If $Q$ reduces to $L$ then $\overline{Q}$ reduces to $\overline{L}$

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, polynomial-time-reductions

The following exercise is taken from Chapter 17 of *Languages and Machines* by Thomas Sudkamp:

> Let $Q$ be a language reducible to a language $L$ in polynomial time. Prove that $\overline{Q}$ is reducible to $\overline{L}$ in polynomial time.

I am not sure if my solution idea is correct. Anyone knows the correct solution of this exercise?

My idea is: I use the definition of NP-complete. Q is in NP class and L is NP-complete. The function f to reducible in polynomial time Q to L, is also the function f to reducible in polynomial time notQ to notL

Comment: Could you tell us your solution idea, and why you're not sure it's correct?

Comment: I use the definition of NP-complete. Q is in NP class and L is NP-complete. The function f to reducible in polynomial time Q to L, is also the function f to reducible in polynomial time  notQ to notL.

Comment: This seems completely fine. Perhaps you can add such an answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks. updated my question

Comment: Wait..  In the question I see no assumption that $Q \in \textrm{NP}$ or that $L$ is $\textrm{NP}$-complete. In fact those assumptions are unnecessary.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Answer (score 2):

By hypothesis $Q \le_p L$, i.e., there exists a poly-time computable function $f(x)$ such that $x \in L \iff f(x) \in Q$. Then: 
$$
x \in \overline{L} \iff x \not\in L \iff f(x) \not\in Q \iff f(x) \in \overline{Q}.
$$

Therefore $\overline{L} \le_p \overline{Q}$.